# files list for package is not a regular file? Need help with dpkg error

Tags: drivers, apt, upgrade, package-management, dpkg

I am having some troubles with my packages on my system. I run ubuntu 16.04 LTS and tried to install printer drivers for the brother MFC-L2700DW printer today. I may say I have only very limited experience with packages and all that.

Their "drivers" are a simple bash file force installing some kind of packages if I see this correctly and I suspect this to be the cause for my problems - but this is just a guess. (file here: http://pastebin.com/JVrb2C1A)

When I wanted to remove the drivers again I got some errors and after doing `sudo apt-get autoremove`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 6 not upgraded.
```

I get those errors when I do `sudo apt-get upgrade`

```
florian@PC15-085:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  gnome-calendar ifupdown libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 openssl
6 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/4.438 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4.096 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgpod4:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'geoip-database' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'liblocale-gettext-perl' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list for package 'libyaml-0-2:amd64' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Can someone help me solve those errors? Everything I tried to remove / upgrade / reinstall failed and at this point I just want to get rid of them.

EDIT:

So I took a look at what the files list file actually was and instead of a simple txt file with paths in it, it was somehow a kind of link pointing to a directory.

Now I did maybe not the most clever thing, and deleted it. This lead to `apt-get upgrade` now saying the file list is missing. I then created a new file called `libyaml-0-2:amd64.list` wich I could not edit somehow because of the `:` (forgive my lack of linux knowledge here if this is something common), so I made a txt file test and filled it with the file list info from `http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libyaml-0-2/filelist` and renamed it to `libyaml-0-2:amd64.list`

Now, when I do `apt-get upgrade` I get the next error:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list for package 'debianutils' is not a regular file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

And a look at this file shows:

```
florian@PC15-085:/var/lib/dpkg/info$ ls debianutils.*
debianutils.md5sums  debianutils.postinst  debianutils.postrm

debianutils.list:
dependency_links.txt  entry_points.txt  PKG-INFO  top_level.txt
```

debianutils.list is not a txt file, but a directory. I dont know if this is supposed to be like this and before I start deleting more stuff I would want some insight by someone who actually knows how this is supposed to look.